# About Google Play Merchant

Tags: google-play, merchant-account

What bank account can i use in Philippines for Google play merchant, I want to sell apps but my current card don't have swift code..Can I use Debit card?
My current card is Smart Money Debit card
I want to apply in BDO ATM Debit card and I don't know if this card is accepted by google merchant

Comment: please help me   guys 

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is not about programming